# Google Analytics and Iframe cross domain problem

Tags: javascript, iframe, google-analytics

We host iframes on CloudFront but we call the Google Analytics code and iframe on a Dropbox page. The problem is Google Analytics code runs on the server that has been called(Dropbox) not in the parent(CloudFront). I have looked into this:
http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/tracking/gaTrackingSite.html#trackingIFrames

But we don't want to grab the iframe by the id and do pageTracker._getLinkerUrl on that. We will put this iframe code on a client side and don't want to put more code in the iframe that we will give to the client. I have also tried doing an Ajax load but still doesn't work. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Why not just give them some piece of JS that will write the iframe dynamically?

Comment: The problem is we don't want to give the client more code to put on their website. I don't think there is an easy way of doing this without adding more code?

Comment: When you say client, please make a distinction between a "business client" and a browser client...this is very confusing otherwise.  If you mean browser client throughout - it doesn't make much sense as all the code will be loaded by the "client" regardless of whether its inside the iframe or outside the iframe.

Answer (score 1):

I think `document.domain` could help you out, but there's a little more to it, as explained here: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/09/15/iframes-onload-and-documentdomain/